# Check if mail is read, gmail api

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, gmail-api

I am working on a gmail app (you can probably tell if you read my other questions), I can list my first 10 email, however I have no way of knowing weather they are read or not. Does anyone know how I would even go about this? Thanks!

Comment: No idea how you're doing this, but wouldn't that just be that `if (email == opened) { //mark as read }`? Depending on how you fetch the mails, whether or not you have a database backend, and so forth, it will be different solutions. You could even just store a boolean in localStorage based on viewed or not (not viewed == 0, viewed == 1)

Comment: I also thought it would be this simple, However the way the gmail api works is that it uses labels, if an email is read it does not have the unread label. however according to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels it does not return simply if it has the label, Therefor I am wondering how I would check whether it has the unread label or not. Sorry if this was unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I list my newest message:

### Request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

### Response

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "158d822014b7887b",
   "threadId": "158d822014b7887b"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "17683191771541399341",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 2
}
```

And then get the message:

### Request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/158d822014b7887b?format=metadata&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

### Response

```
{
 "id": "158d822014b7887b",
 "threadId": "158d822014b7887b",
 "labelIds": [
  "UNREAD",
  "CATEGORY_SOCIAL",
  "INBOX"
 ],
 ...
}
```

You can see that the message has a `labelId` with the value of `UNREAD`. If the message doesn't have this `labelId`, it is read.

```
var isRead = message.labelIds.indexOf("UNREAD") === -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

just for anyone else that wants to do this here is a simple piece of code that will do it.

```
if (message.labelIds[0] === 'UNREAD'){
  //do somthing
}
```

Comment: The `UNREAD` string doesn't necessarily have to be first in the array. I updated my answer.

Comment: From my experience (which could very easily be wrong) it has always been first. In any event thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following request to only fetch unread messages

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is:unread&maxResults=1&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Reference: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en